# Showing a set of non-zero matrices that are similar to $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ are a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

I'm currently studying linear algebra and came across this question that asks to state whether or not if $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$, then the set $S$ containing all $n\times n$ matrices that are similar $A$ is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$

I know that two similar matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan form so the set $S$ contains all $n \times n$ matrices that have the same Jordan form as $A$. But I can't seem to connect the next dot to show whether or not $S$ is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ or not.

Any hints and guidance will be great

Answer (score 5):

Well, for $A\ne 0$, is the zero matrix $0\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C})$ similar to $A$?

Comment: why would $0\in S$?

Comment: For $S$ to be a subspace it must contain $0$.

Comment: aren't there only 2 criterions for subspace? closed under scalar multiplication and addition + non-empty?

Comment: @JakeStratus Closed under scalar multiplication is what gets you $0.$

Comment: I'm still kind of lost, do you mind walking through the logic?

Comment: It is asking a question. A yes-or-no question. Suppose $A \neq 0$. Is the zero matrix similar to $A$? What do you think? Please think about that question. Is the zero matrix similar to $A$? After you have thought about it, and you feel like you know the answer, then you should think about how that might relate to whether or not $S$ is a subspace. Please, first think about whether the zero matrix is similar to $A$. Then second, think about how the first question relates to whether $S$ is a subspace.

Comment: It's true that there are only two criterions.  but they imply that zero is _always_ in a subspace.  that gives an easy way to tell right off the bat that it's not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  A slick trick for  eliminating certain sets as vector spaces, or subspaces, is to check whether the zero vector $\vec0$ is an element of the set.   It must be, because for instance, $0\cdot v=0$ has to be an element of the set.  Keep this in mind.

(I still remember when my housemate Kai Behrend, at the time a phd student at Berkeley, pointed this out to me.  And I have used it dozens of times.  I was already pretty good at linear algebra, but didn't know...)